# Cannot copy or move uploaded files in Windows Server

Tags: php, iis, upload, windows-server-2012-r2

(The question was initially asked in Server Fault. I move it to here, because I don't have enough credit to start a bounty over there.)

I am trying to make my `Windows Server 2012 R2` to host a [webpage](http://test.addbba.com/indexfile.html) where users could upload a file.

```
<!-- indexfile.html -->
<form action="uploadfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Browse for File to Upload: <br>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="80"> <br>
    <input type="submit" id="u_button" name="u_button" value="Upload the file">
</form>


// uploadfile.php
<?php
  $file_result = "";
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  $file_result .= "No File Uploaded or Invalid File ";
  $file_result .= "Error Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
  $file_result .=
  "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>" .
  "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>" .
  "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br>" .
  "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

  if (chmod("C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test", 0777)) 
     $file_result .= "chmod sucessful!<br>";
  else 
     $file_result .= "chomod NOT sucessful!<br>";

  copy($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test/" . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

  $file_result .= "File Upload Successful!";

  echo $file_result;
  }
?>
```

The problem is, files can be uploaded into `C:\Windows\Temp\`, whereas `copy` does not work. As consequence, `C:\inetpub\testaddbbacom\test` is always empty. I did try to change the permission of this folder by `chmod`, but it does not really work. Here is a comparaison of the permissions of two folders:

[image]

I also tried `move_uploaded_file`, but it did not work either, probably due to the same permission reason...

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace,

```
copy($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test/" . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
```

With the following,

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

the difference is use file name i.e $_FILES["file"]["name"]) and not $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) in destination path.

Comment: Great, it does work this time... I don't know why it didn't work before. So what's wrong with `copy`?

Comment: try my same statement with copy instead of move_uploaded_file, I never used copy :D

Comment: Indeed, copy works now... It seems that `.tmp` is only valid in the folder `Temp`, so we have to rename it outside...